# Extracting name of an image from an src attribute (url)

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape images using JSoup and don't understand a piece of code that I stumbled upon.

Part of the code: (src in this case is defined as an absolute url)

```
private static void getImages(String src) throws IOException {

    String folder = null;

    //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute
    int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

    if (indexname == src.length()) { // Don't understand this
        src = src.substring(1, indexname);
    }

    indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
    String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());

    // more code
}
```

I don't understand the `if` statement. More specifically, when will `indexname` ever equal the length of src?

Comment: If the `indexname == src.length()` then the `String` ends in a slash.

Comment: its checking to see if the string src ends in an backslash.  If it does, it removes it and checks again, that way it pulls the last section of the url, even if it ends in a backslash.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no. This code has a bug. indexname will never be equal to src.length().

Comment: What interests me is why there is `src.substring(1, indexname);`. If purpose was to remove last slash then it should be `src.substring(0, indexname);`

Comment: @Marshall Slash, not backslash.

Comment: @JBNizet That's true because `src.length()` isn't part of the String. Still. I think that's what they wanted it to do. `if (indexname == src.length() - 1) {`;

Comment: `src.lastIndexOf()` will never return value `>= src.length()`

Comment: @JBNizet thanks that's what I thought. Although the reason this confused me twofold is because I found this if statement in 2 different sources describing the same thing, so I thought I was missing something. I'll update the answer when SO allows me to

Comment: Can we know where did you find this code?

Comment: @Pshemo http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/html/download-images-from-a-website-using-jsoup/ AND in the source code provided in the description here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP0T4rHVG0c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assume every source you find on the internet is good.

That piece of code has many problems.

1. Indeed, the only case where the result of `String.lastIndexOf` is the length of the source string is when the search string is "". So that `if` block is never executed.
2. The operation inside that `if` block (delete the first character of the string) is not really helpful.
3. It is perfectly legal to add slashes to a URL even after the image name. Try adding '?/' to an image name in a URL.
4. It is also perfectly legal not to have an image name at all. There could be the name of a script with parameters there, such as "http://example.com/generate-captcha.php?param1=foo&param2=bar" (not a real link, just an example).
5. You could even have nothing at all after the domain name.

Since there is no law that says that a URL actually has to have a file name after the last slash, or that the file name has to be the name of the actual image, then this code works only part of the time.